# bind() throws an error EINVAL, UDP server on Linux

Tags: c, linux, server, udp, bind

I have a problem with a simple UDP server realization. I have the following code that works great in a little standalone application. But if I just copy-paste that into another, more complicated application, it fails - `bind()` function returns -1 and sets errno to 22 (`EINVAL`). This another application also has a TCP server that works good and it starts on start of the application. Please guys, your ideas, why have I the problem. Thanks in advance!

**UPD:** By the way, `getsockname()` function sometimes fails too in that application (It says that the handle is invalid).

**UPD 2:** thanks to **fbynite** I fixed a typo in the code. Now bind() returns no errors, but recvfrom() is freezing. Of course a datagram was sent from a client

```
int handle = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

if (handle < 0)
{
    std::cout << "socket(): " << std::strerror(errno)) << std::endl;
    return;
}

sockaddr_in addr;

addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
addr.sin_port = htons(6660);

if (bind(handle, (sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)
{
    std::cout << "bind(): " << std::strerror(errno)) << std::endl;
    close(handle);
    return;
}
else
{
    sockaddr cl;
    socklen_t clLen;
    char buffer[100];

    int bytes = recvfrom(handle, buffer, 100, 0, &cl, &clLen);

    buffer[bytes] = '\0';
    std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: the code you've posted has an error, is it a typo? `(bind(handle, (sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr) < 0))` should be `(bind(handle, (sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)` - note the parens at the end.

Comment: yes, it is a typo, thank you!

Comment: I fixed the typo in the code, now bind() returns >= 0. But the code is freezing on recvfrom. Datagram from the client was sent of course

Comment: `recvfrom` is incorrect as it is, try initializing `clLen` first: `clLen = sizeof(cl)` before passing it to `recvfrom`.

Comment: What for should it be initialized while it is an output parameter? It is allocated by static memory but what for an exact value is needed? Anyway, I have tried to use your note - no effect :(

Comment: `recvfrom` is blocking, it's likely it hasn't received anything.

Comment: I will try to resend the datagram for an experiment

Comment: I've tried now. No effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a little out of sync. Actually the server was starting after the client has sent a datagram. The problem is solved.